# Why does my variable sannolikhet only print out zero?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create a program that counts the probability out of `n` people that atleast 2 persons have the same birthday.

```
int main()
{


int n;
double sannolikhet = 1;

cout << "Skriv in antal personer mellan 2 - 182: ";
cin >> n;
```

Here I ask the user to write in the amount of people between the numbers 2 - 182.

```
while (n < 2 || n > 182)
{
    cout << "OBS! Skriv in ett tal mellan 2 - 182: \n";
    cout << "Skriv in antal personer mellan 2 - 182: ";
    cin >> n;
}
```

Here is the problem, every time `i` changes I want it to store the previous calculation in `sannolikhet`. I want the for loop to count like this "365/365 * 364/365 * 363/365 ... (366-n)/365". When it prints out sannolikhet in the end it just shows zero.

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    sannolikhet = sannolikhet * ((366 - i) / 365); 
}



cout << "Sannolikheten att två personer har samma födelsedag är: " << fixed << setprecision(7) << sannolikhet <<" procent";


return 0;

}
```

Comment: `sannoliket` is not zero.   The result of `((366 - i) / 365)` is for numerous values of `i`, since division of two values of type `int` results in a value of type `int`, with rounding toward zero.

Answer (score 2):

With integer division, the answer is automatically turned into an integer, <s>rounding it down</s>.
Edit: As corrected by @john, the answer is truncated to an integer rather than rounded 
So 364/365 will evaluate to 0

try replacing `sannolikhet = sannolikhet * ((366 - i) / 365);` 
to `sannolikhet = sannolikhet * ((366.0 - i) / 365.0);`

Comment: Strictly speaking integer division rounds towards zero. In other words it truncates not rounds down.

Comment: I'm new to programming so I keep making mistakes like this. Now it works like it should, thanks for the help!

Comment: The division needs `double`, not the subtraction.  Alternative: `(366 - i) / 365.0`